# How to set cursor position in a popup buffer?

Tags: vimscript, cursorline, popup-menu

I'm tinkering with popups and trying to open one, select a line (namely set the cursor line by pressing mapped keys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>)), then close it. The problem is that I cannot select a line, despite the `setpos` function's doc says that one can use it to set the cursor line in another buffer and that the `setpos` function returns 0 if the cursor line can be set (I checked it with `echo setpos(…)`, it returned 0):

> Returns 0 when the position could be set, -1 otherwise. An error message is given if {expr} is invalid.

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> to set the line, it is set in the current buffer, not in the popup one and the cursorline highlighting is not changed in the popup window.

This is the screen shot and below is the script:

[image: screen shot of the popup]

```
let s:popup_content = ['line one',
  \'line one',
  \'line three']
let s:popup_win_id = v:none
let s:popup_buf_id = v:none
let s:cur_line = 1

function! Omni_create()
  let s:popup_win_id = popup_create(s:popup_content,
    \#{
      \pos: 'botleft',
      \line: 'cursor-1',
      \col: 'cursor',
      \title: 'some ttl:',
      \cursorline: 1,
    \}
  \)
  let s:popup_buf_id = winbufnr(s:popup_win_id)
  noremap <Esc> :call Omni_delete()<CR>
  noremap <C-N> :call Omni_cursor_next()<CR>
  "noremap <C-P :call Omni_cursor_prev()<CR>
endfunction

function! Omni_delete()
  call popup_close(s:popup_win_id)
  unmap <Esc>
  unmap <C-N>
  "unmap <C-P>
  normal gi
endfunction

function! Omni_cursor_next()
  let s:cur_line += 1
  "everything is echoed correctly
  echo 'here'
  echo s:cur_line
  echo s:popup_buf_id
  call setpos('.', [s:popup_buf_id, s:cur_line, 1, 0])
endfunction

inoremap <C-X><C-O> <Esc>:call Omni_create()<CR>
```

So could anyone please suggest how can I approach this? Either what's being wrong with the `setpos` function or should I use something different?

Comment: If you want to [scroll in a popup](https://github.com/lacygoill/wiki/blob/master/vim/popup.md#scrolling) use `win_execute()` + `:norm!`.  You may also need to reset the `firstline` key.

Comment: I think `popup_menu` does what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is trying to mimic popup menu by popup window, it's complicate, I changed it to use arrow keys to scroll popup window in normal mode, it's only purpose is to show you how to change cursor in popup window:

```
noremap <buffer> <down> :call Omni_cursor(1)<CR>
noremap <buffer> <up> :call Omni_cursor(0)<CR>
noremap <buffer> <C-x><c-o> :call Omni_create()<CR>

function Omni_create()
  let d = #{ pos: 'botleft', line: 'cursor-1', col: 'cursor',
        \    title: 'some ttl:', cursorline: 1, maxheight: 3, }
  let s:popup_win_id = popup_create(map(range(10), {i,v->string(v)}), d)
endfunction

" scroll popup window, change current line
function Omni_cursor(down)
  call win_execute(s:popup_win_id, a:down ? '+' : '-')
  call popup_setoptions(s:popup_win_id, #{cursorline: 1})
  call win_execute(s:popup_win_id, 'let l:line = getline(".")')
  call setline('.', line)
endfunction

" for debug purpose
call popup_clear()
```

All map is in created in normal mode.

Popup window won't change your current buffer, so `setpos` won't work, you need to use `win_execute`.

Another thing about popup window is you might need to change a property to trigger redraw, above program reset `'cursorline'` option to trigger redraw everytime you scroll.